# JSP or Servlets?

Tags: html, database, jsp, servlets

My question is:

I'm doing a website that requires to update some div contents (img,h1,p) based on a database data (I'm doing some queries).

So which one is better for this, JSP or Servlets?

Answer (score 1):

you should use both of them. the concept behind my answer is separation of concerns. ui should be separated from logical part or business processing part. this is why MVC design pattern come in existence. 
The batter design include

1. JSP as View
2. Servlet as controller
3. POJO as service to access models

use servlet to dispatch the request to jsp ,when processing is done .use pojo for business logic and access them in servlet. after all is done set sheared variables as request/session attributes so that you can access them in view.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, JSP(s) are compiled into Servlet(s) so neither is "better" then the other. I would suggest you put the business logic into Controller Servlet(s) and your presentation in JSP(s). I think you'll find there is a reason both continue to exist in the Java world.

Answer (score -1):

It must follow MVC pattern.

From JSP call a method in Controller which will then call DAO layer and get the data.

Based on the data you receive, you can process it in the JSP using scriptlet or jstl tags.

It's better to create a reusable JSTL tag if you are planning to use it in multiple pages.

So JSP is better in that use case